# Wordpress site not working in IE

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer

This site works perfectly well in all major browsers, but when I tested it on explorer it in explorer 9 or earlier versions, it went insane: The margin-auto didn't work, all the absolute positions went to different locations, the menu disappeared and so on...

I am using a "naked" html5-blank-master theme, which works in ie on other sites I've created.

I've tried placing the "`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`" with no results.

Please help.

Here is the link to the site [MY SITE](http://www.websitedesignmadesimple.com/)

Comment: When you start to become more familiar with coding and CSS you will learn to create more simple coding to refrain from such errors. Unfortunately you will have to post your source code some how, of the header.php and index.php and stylesheet.css Most of the time with Internet Explorer, it becomes confused when positioning is absolute, it works best with relative and extra containers.

Comment: I never had such problems until today. All my other sites work fine with IE.

Comment: Well, I manipulated the code and used a JS script called "CSS Browser Selector" that enables me to create different css to different browsers and most problems are solved. One thing I still can't understand is why isn't the jQuery slider working? It works perfectly well in other browsers and other jQuery scripts do work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You have white space, or something else, before the doctype. Some/most versions of IE would go into quirks mode if there was anything in front of the doctype including spaces. Remove that and see where we stand.

Comment: There's no white space. I managed to fix most of the inconsistencies by now, except for the jQuery slider. This is peculiar because other jQuery scripts do work and the slider works fine on any other browser.

Comment: @SaharSoffer - To the contrary, you have two tabs, I believe, before the doctype. Do a ctrl-U to see the doctype indented.

Comment: That's strange. I see now that the tabs appear in the source view, but when I open the header.php in wp editor, I don't see them.

Comment: Check functions.php if it has those tabs.